# "-2" Being added to end of URL (no duplicate pages, no pages in trash)

Tags: permalinks, pages, urls

I have a page called "Orlando" and for some reason the page url is `/orlando-2/`. I have never made another "Orlando" page on this site and there are no pages living in the trash. There is also no other page with the word "Orlando" in it. I know this happens when you have multiple pages of the same name but can't find any fix if there are no dups.

Thanks

Comment: Is there an image called `orlando`? Search your database if you can.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee yes there is. I just deleted it and tried to go back to the page and change the URL and its still forcing `-2`

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Never mind, it is all working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Duplicates don't just come from Pages and Posts, WordPress also defines Images and Files from the Media Library as "Posts". This means if you have a file / image in the Media Library with the same name as a page, it will assign the next duplicate a `-2` ( from the [`wp_unique_post_slug()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug) function ) so there's no URL conflicts.

TL;DR - Duplicate? Search for Pages, Posts, *and* Images.